# Plot data for a range of years in Wolfram Alpha

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I am trying to compare a bunch of statistics in Wolfram Alpha, but haven't been able to figure out how to configure the plot/graph:

For example, a search for `population of Egypt vs Vietnam` shows a plot of the entire population history. Is it possible to restrict it to a specific range? It does not seem to understand inputs such as:

- `population of Egypt vs Vietnam, 1970-1990`
- `population of Egypt vs Vietnam, 1970..1990`
- `population of egypt vs vietnam, [1970..1990]`
- `(population of egypt vs vietnam)[1970..1990]`

And others I have tried.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get is by trying the following:

```
Egypt Vietnam | population | 1970 to 1990
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it looks like at least it marks the period on the graph, which is better than before. However, one of the issues is that in some cases the vertical axis in the graph is "haywire" during a period, and makes the rest of the graph hard to read. For example: `Egypt Israel | population growth | 1950 to 2017`. If it's not possible to hide the rest of the graph, is it possible to restrict the Y axis?

Comment: *"If it's not possible to hide the rest of the graph, is it possible to restrict the Y axis?"* I am afraid not. For this as well as other features you would have to [go pro](https://www.wolframalpha.com/pro/)